# How to add font in (Setup Factory Application)

Tags: fonts, directory, copy, installation, setup-factory

I want to create a install file for the program with the **Setup Factory** application.

How do I add my fonts to **Setup Factory Application** and then copy them to the client computer in the **C:\Windows\Fonts** folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a license to redistribute the Microsoft font, then try to add the file from the folder where you originally downloaded it... When adding the font file from a different folder than `C:\Windows\Fonts`, it should be accepted by Setup Factory, and the target folder will be set to `%FontsFolder%` automatically:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBBma.png)